# Keep UIWebView play audio after PopViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

As stated in the subject, how I am going to keep the audio playing inside the UIWebView after popping the view. As what I have read and done before, the audio will be playing for good 3 seconds and stop after that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You can't do it. Coz your webView will be removed after popping the controller

Comment: @mojo u can implement a singleton which would play a music. Then it keeps audio playing until u stop